# RNN-Model for Extracting real-valued sequences

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoders

I am trying to extract a real valued sequence from a larger sequence. 
For example, a function generates a sequence by doubling the previous value:

```
1.1, 2.2, 4.4, 8.8
```

Currently I have trained a LSTM classifier that classifies a sequence based on the trained model of a function:

```
1.1, 2.2, 4.4, 8.8                 =      1
1, 3.5, 2.6, 6                     =      0
.5, 1, 2, 4                        =      1
1, -3., -5.5, 6                    =      0   .. and so on
```

is there a way to extend this to extract sequences out of a combined sequence?

```
1.1, 1.5, 2.2, -3.7, 4.4, -6.8, 6.9, 7.7, 8.8      =     1.1, 2.2, 4.4, 8.8
                                                              or
                                                      1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Extracting the most likely sequence that fits into the trained classifier or predictor model.

What's a suitable RNN-model approach to extracting a sequence that fits a model among a longer "noisy" sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to train a generative LSTM model than a LSTM classifer. If I have a sequence 
`1.1, 1.5, 2.2, -3.7, 4.4, -6.8, 6.9, 7.7, 8.8`, 
the model and loss function should be as follow:

```
   1     0     1     0          1
   ^     ^     ^     ^          ^
   |     |     |     |          |
o->L1  ->L2  ->L3  ->L4 ->... ->L9
   ^     ^     ^     ^          ^
   |     |     |     |          |
   1.1   1.5   2.2  -3.7  ...   8.8
```

where $o$ represents the zero state.
While a cell needs to know the numbers afterwards, you may try using the bidirectional LSTM.